# Angle between two complex vectors

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, vectors

I'm trying to find the angle between $p = 2-2i$ and $q = 1-i\sqrt(3)$. I already got the answer as $\frac{\pi}{12}$ by subtracting the angles of $p$ and $q$ ($\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4}$). I am trying to do the same using dot product, but Im not sure how to go about it.

Comment: The definition of complex multiplication is multiply the magnitudes and add the angles.  If you conjugate one of the numbers, that negates its angle.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: What do you mean by conjugate one of the numbers? What numbers?

Comment: Or, divide $p/q$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to find the angle with the vector dot product. The two vectors are,

$$\vec{p}=(2,-2),\>\>\>\>\>\vec{q}=(1,-\sqrt 3)$$

Their dot product is

$$\vec{p}\cdot\vec{q} = pq\cos\theta$$

Then, $\cos\theta$ can be computed as below,

$$\cos\theta = \frac{\vec{p}\cdot\vec{q}}{pq}
=\frac{2+2\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 8 \sqrt 4}=\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}=\cos 15^\circ$$

Thus,

$$\theta =15^\circ$$

Answer (score 1):

These are not complex vectors. They're still really since all the components are real. You may write each of them as $(2,-2),\,(1,-\sqrt 3).$ Then their dot product is $(2)(1)+(-2)(-\sqrt 3)=2+2\sqrt 3.$

Recall that for two vectors $a,b$ with an angular separation of $\phi,$ we have that $a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos\phi.$ Can you now continue?